# How to return a boolean value regarding success and still include the http status code in python?

Tags: python, return-value, http-error

I want to be able to return success when a method call succeeds but still be able to return the http error code when it fails.

Obviously the only numeric value that evaluates as False is 0, so returning http codes as numerics will evaluate all of them as true.

I have the impression that the solution is to return an object that evaluates as true only for 200-2xx values and that also converts to number so people can compare it.

Are you aware about anyone that had a similar approach? -- I don't like the idea of raising exceptions in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Just return **two** results, the success flag and the http response:

```
def some_function():
    return success, http_response
```

and use tuple assignment:

```
success, response = some_function()
if success:
```

The approach that the [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) takes is to return a response object *always*, then give you the choice of raising an exception based on the response code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
```

where the [`Response.raise_for_status()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) gives users of your API the *option* to raise an exception. The other option is to test for the status code:

```
if not 200 <= response.status_code <= 299:
    # problem status response
```

Both of these approaches have the advantage that they are *explicit*. Don't try to overload a return value with multiple meanings. If a HTTP response outside the 2xx range is an exception, treat it as such by raising an exception.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach but to my knowledge it will not work, because a tuple like `(False, 401)` would eval as `True`.

Comment: That's why you need to unpack the returned tuple, see the second code snippet. I don't test `if some_function()`, I test `success`, which is the *first* value in the returned tuple.

Comment: If unpacking isn't what you want to do, then you need a class object that has repr of your Boolean and an attribute containing your status code.

Comment: @MarcelWilson if I would have to unpack it wouldn't be a simple solution anymore, instead of unpacking Exceptions seems to be much better.

Answer (score 3):

It's not Pythonic to rely on return values to indicate success/failure, *especially* in a function that's supposed to return something in the first place.

Just return the HTTP code. If the function fails, raise an exception (create a custom exception -- `TimeoutError`, `UnknownHostError`... and make the HTTP code one of its attributes).

In addition, take a look at what the Requests library (http://requests.readthedocs.org) does. Response objects have a `raise_for_status` method, which will raise an exception if their HTTP code isn't in the 2xx range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I assume you just want to catch Http errors. In that case, is this what you mean? (I usually use the build in module "urllib2" to do http requests/ open urls)

```
 import urllib2
 try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url) #open a url
 except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    if err.code == 404:
            print "Page not found!"
    elif err.code == 403:
        print "Access denied!"
    else:
        print "Something happened! Error code", err.code
 except urllib2.URLError, err:
    validationerror = err
    print(" ")
    print("Connection error")
    print(err)
    print "Can not connect to annotation review server"
    print(" ")
 except:
    validationerror = (sys.exc_info()[0])
    print(validationerror)
```